# I am unable to run this .py file. Recieved many errors. Couldn't figure out what's happeneing

Tags: python

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def talk(text):
  engine.say(text)
  engine.runAndWait()


 def take_command():
try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('listening...')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        command = command.lower()
        if 'cyther' in command:
            command = command.replace('cyther', '')
            print(command)
except:
    pass
return command


def run_alexa():
  command = take_command()
  print(command)
  if 'play' in command:
      song = command.replace('play', '')
      talk('playing ' + song)
      pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
elif 'time' in command:
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
    talk('Current time is ' + time)
elif 'who the heck is' in command:
    person = command.replace('who the heck is', '')
    info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
    print(info)
    talk(info)
elif 'date' in command:
    talk('sorry, I have a headache')
elif 'are you single' in command:
    talk('I am in a relationship with wifi')
elif 'joke' in command:
    talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
else:
    talk('Please say the command again.')


while True:
  run_alexa()
```

The Terminal Gave:

```
C:\Users\Prakash\Desktop\romantic-alexa-main>C:/Users/Prakash/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/Prakash/Desktop/romantic-alexa-main/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib  # comtypes
ImportError: cannot import name 'SpeechLib' from 'comtypes.gen' (C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 121, in WINFUNCTYPE
    return _win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]
KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_long'>), 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Prakash/Desktop/romantic-alexa-main/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = comtypes.client.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 110, in GetBestInterface
    mod = GetModule(tlib)
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 118, in GetModule
    mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 198, in _CreateWrapper
    mod = _my_import(fullname)
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 19, in _my_import
    return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\_C866CA3A_32F7_11D2_9602_00C04F8EE628_0_5_4.py", line 253, in <module>
    ( ['out', 'retval'], POINTER(VARIANT), 'NewPosition' )),
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 323, in __setattr__
    self._make_methods(value)
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 692, in _make_methods
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
    class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):
TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.
```

Anyone know what's going on?
Just saw this project randomly and started to type the same. Imported all the modules required but I am stuck at this error.

Comment: The code is not indented correctly. Also, this question is off-topic on stackoverflow. If you have a specific problem, we might be able to help, but to fix all errors within a program isn't really what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: You need a [example]. Currently there's too much unrelated code.

Comment: Anyway, it's probably https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/29#issuecomment-737194669-permalink .

Answer (score 0):

one of the errors that you are doing here is:

1st: you should use (for example in your code) `if command == "cyther":`
*do what ever you want in it* this should be the format of all if and elif statements in your code(replace: `if command in "Example":` --> to `if command == "Example":`)

im not familiar with anything in `run_alexa()` function, but the thing stated above should fix most of your issues.

Hopefully this helped you, and feel free to ask any question regarding this :)